# Ancillary statistic is independent of minimal sufficient statistic in the location exponential family?

Tags: probability, statistics

This is the exercise 6.11(b) of Statistical Inference Book by Casella and Berger.

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample. Let

$$f(x|\theta)=e^{-(x-\theta)}, \theta <x<\infty, -\infty<\theta<\infty$$

A minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$ is $X_{(1)}$. Let $X_{(1)}<...<X_{(n)}$ be the ordered sample, and define $Y_i = X_{(n)}-X_{(i)},i=1,...,n-1$.

We need to show the set $(Y_1,...,Y_{n-1})$ is independent of the minimal sufficient statistic $X_{(1)}$.

I don't know how to do, but my idea is to find the joint pdf of $(Y_1,...,Y_{n-1}, X_{(1)})$, then I can find this joint pdf can be factored out separately. Then I can conclude they are independent. But how can I find this joint pdf?

The online solution:

Define $Y_n = X_{(1)}$. Then the joint pdf of $(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ is

$$f(y_1,...,y_n)=n! e^{-n(y_1-\theta) }e^{-(n-1)y_n} \prod_{i=2}^{n-1} e^{y_i}, 0< y_{n-1}<y_{n-2}<...<y_1, 0<y_n <\infty$$

How to get the above?

Comment: This looks like a Basu's theorem problem.

Comment: @Clarinetist To use Basu's theorem, we have to verify $X_{(1)}$ is complete, which could be verified. I don't know. But the online solution used my idea.